# Проверка буквосочетаний из Х символов в строке на совпадение

Tags: c

Надо написать проверку для строки, в которой происходит сравнение всех буквенных словосочетаний из Х символов. Если такие повторение буквосочетаний присутствует, то выводит информацию, что проверка не пройдена.

Возможно немного не понимаю функционирование массивов в С, надеюсь на любые подсказки

**Примечание**: запрещено использование библиотек string.h, ctype.h

**Как решал**: Создавал 2 вспомогательных массива. В первый массив кладется буквосочетание из первых Х символов строки, во второй кладется сочетание из вторых Х символов строки. И дальше происходит сравнение постепенно двигая циклом ячейки из которых берутся буквосочетаний во вспомогательные массивы.

**Дополнение по коду**: par - это Х; sub1, sub2 - вспомогательные массивы; heslo - строка для проверки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char heslo[] = "HeHeslo123!";

par = 2;

char sub1[par]; 
char sub2[par];

int main (){

    int indexCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < par; i++){
        sub1[i] = heslo[i];  
        for (int k = i * par; k < (i+1)*(par*2); k++){
        sub2[indexCounter] = heslo[k];
        indexCounter++;
        if (sub1 == sub2){
            printf("Sovpadenie\n");
        } else {
            printf("Net sovpadeniy\n");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Одинаковые подстроки искать, или что-то иное? Примеры не помешают

Comment: Постановка задачи непонятна, но оператор *if (sub1 == sub2)* - заведомый вздор. :-( Вы хотели сравнить **строки**, а сравниваете **указатели** на строки. Эти указатели - константы (они просто указывают на область памяти) и не могут быть равными никак.

Comment: Да, строки на С сравниваются с помощью функции *strcmp()*. Если её использовать нельзя - напишите эквивалент. Это займёт 3 строки исходного  текста.